# Не работает ajax запрос Asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Есть контроллер с методом

```
public class TestController: Controller{
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetQuestionWithAnswers(){
    var answers = qaDb.Answers.Include(p=>p.Question);
    var data = answers.ToList();
    return Json(data,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
{
```

}

С ними всё хорошо.
И есть js скрипт, где я с помощью ajax пытаюсь вытянуть данные.

```
var testContainer = [];

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"../test/getquestionwithanswers",
        type:"Post",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({}),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result){
            for (var i = 0; i<result.length; i++){
                testContainer.push(result[i]);
        }
 });
});
```

Но в итоге на стороне клиента данные не приходят - в чём моя ошибка?

Comment: Что показывает консоль на AJAX запрос? Ответ в любом случае должен быть... HTTP 404, HTTP500 и т.д..

Comment: юзайте https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/10.3.php это удобнее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя опечатка в скобках скрипта. Отформатировал:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "../order/getquestionwithanswers",
                type: "Post",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify({}),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    debugger;
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                        testContainer.push(result[i]);
                    }
                }
            })
        });
```

После этого результат возвращается